# System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, bukkit

In Spigot I am creating a daily rewards plugin where I will need to store the amount of days users have logged in for in a row but my main trouble is System.currentTimeMillis(). I want to create a server time which shows the hours and minutes. When it gets to a set time like 1AM or 5AM or such if a player joins they have logged in for the next day (as well as if they are online). Another thing I am adding is if a user stays online for a set time like half an hour they get a reward then if they stay online for about 1 hour a bigger reward and it gradually increases. Does System.currentTimeMillis() restart everytime the server restarts? How should I go about this?

Comment: Here's the javadoc. It explains what System.currentTimeMillis() does. All the other classes and methods of the JDK are documented too. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As javadoc of System.currentTimeMillis() says it returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

So the answer is no it does not restart everytime the server restarts.

Answer (score 1):

System.currentTimeMillis() will just give you current system time at any instant. I suppose your use case is to measure login duration on per user basis. I would look to maintain this in per user session object.

Comment: Yea which is why I mentioned the daily rewards part as well as the timed rewards part.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) which allows you to decode the date:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // arguments allow to set time zone

// one of them:
calendar.setTime(new Date());
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

System.out.println("MONTH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("HOUR: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative, I'll be sure to try it.